# Change model property from view in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am working in the mean stack, where I have an Article schema defined in Mongoose. One of the attributes is "approved" which I'm using to let admins approve a certain article from the admin dashboard.

I'd like to modify the approved property using a button from the browser. I have the following code:

Controller:

```
vm.approveArticle = function (id) {
    if (confirm("You are about to publish this article!")) {
        vm.articleData.approved = true;
    }
};
```

View:

```
<td>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success disabled" ng-show="article.approved">Approved</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="article.approveArticle(art._id)" ng-show="!article.approved">Approve</a>
</td>
```

Currently I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot set property 'approved' of undefined` error, which proves I'm probably doing something wrong.

How can I change the approved property from the view?

Comment: Since your question is about "angularjs" then please only use that tag. MEAN and other terms do not apply when you are only asking about that one component. So if you think something else applies here then it up to **you** to post that content in your question and not leave people guessing.

Comment: What is article? Why do you use `article.approved` in the view, and `vm.articleData.approved` in the controller? Show us a complete view, and a complete controller.

Comment: @JBNizet, article is the article from `articleController as article`

Comment: So, if article is the controller, and the view uses `article.approved`, assuming `vm` is also the controller, why does the JS code use `vm.articleData.approved`, and not `vm.approved`as the view expects it? Where does this `articleData`variable come from?

Answer (score 0):

Unless `vm.approved` is a property whose `get` reads from `vm.articleData.approved`, I think you just want `vm.approved = true` in your controller method.